# TreeSets Sets Within Set

Tags: java, arraylist, treeset

I have started implementing a `TreeSet` in `java`. 
i wish to knows, is it possible to create a set within a set.

For example i need to create a set that gives output

```
{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},(1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})}
```

The problem is that i can't get add to my sets to give the desired output.
I have even tried putting my `treeset` within an `arraylist`.

```
ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>> SET = new ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>();
```

this still doesn't give me my desired result, and makes my code really complicated.

as you can see, the output has 2 sets that are basically elements of a larger set.

Please can anyone help?

I AM NOT ASKING FOR CODE ONLY ADVICE!!!

Comment: Write your own `toString()`  which creates the desired output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet<T>` needs a comparator on `T` in order to arrange the elements inside it. You can cerate a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator that "understands" how to compare `TreeSet`s. This will let the outer tree set decide on the order of the tree sets that you put inside it:

```
TreeSet<TreeSet<Integer>> outer = new TreeSet<TreeSet<Integer>>(
    new Comparator<TreeSet<Integer>>() {
        public int compare(TreeSet<Integer> lhs, TreeSet<Integer> rhs) {
            Iterator<Integer> li = lhs.Iterator();
            Iterator<Integer> ri = rhs.Iterator();
            while (li.hasNext() && ri.hasNext()) {
                int res = li.next().compareTo(ri.next());
                if (res != 0) return res;
            }
            if (li.hasNext()) return 1;
            if (ri.hasNext()) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: this is pretty helpful in what im trying to achieve. I understand what i was doing wrong lol. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of Generics is confusing you.

This:  `ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>> SET = new ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>();`

Doesn't put a list in a list.

To do that you need to do this:

```
TreeSet s = new TreeSet();
TreeSet subset = new TreeSet();
s.add(subset);
```